# Windows update - some settings are managed by your organization

Tags: windows-10, group-policy

[image]

I have a Windows 10 laptop that just finished installing 1803. I go into windows update to check for new updates and it shows me this line of text: "Some settings are managed by your organization". I click "view configured update policies" and it shows that there are 3 policies set by the administrator, as seen in the image above.

I am the only one who uses this computer for personal use only. Is there a way to remove their group policies?

Comment: Are you on a domain? If so, you need the domain administrator. If not, you can use gpedit.msc to change the policies

Comment: Are you using third-party privacy tools such ShutUp10 or W10 Privacy? These may use Group Policy settings in the Registry to control update. If not, the see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/328010/how-to-configure-automatic-updates-by-using-group-policy-or-registry-s

Comment: You can also run gpresult /h command to export the group policy to confirm the situation.

Comment: @InterLinked I am not on a domain. This is my own personal computer.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I don't have those installed.

Comment: @Waka See if this helps: https://i.imgur.com/w8WUftM.png

Comment: @RegisteredUser You can still use Group Policy even if you are not on a domain, if you have the Professional version of Windows or better. You may still have policies that are being applied. Try running "rsop.msc" when you press WIN+R

Comment: @InterLinked, my guess this is Windows 10 *Home*, so the user will not have rsop.msc... Registry editing is needed.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik If his screen says that group policies are being applied, that seems unlikely

Comment: Not at all: it's easy to set Group Policies in the Registry, and the applications I cited do so. Trying to change these settings, e.g. in Privacy, shows the message "Some settings are managed by your organizations." The Group Policy Editor is simply a tool left out of Windows 10 Home to differentiate it from more expensive versions, but most underlying mechanisms are the same.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I have rsop.msc up because i have windows 10 pro. What settings should i change?

Comment: See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/waas-wufb-group-policy

Answer (score 1):

Change the privacy configuration:

**Settings -> Privacy -> Feedback & diagnostics -> Diagnostics and usage data**, change it to **Enhanced**.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/2rbiA4w.png

There is only Basic and full.